# Vertically aligning an image in division

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

I'm currently trying to vertically align an image in an image rotator (SlideDeck). The images currently are all aligned to the top, though I need these to be aligned to the middle. Heights of the images varies.

I've tried out numerous methods, such as with absolute alignment, etc. with no luck.

Please see: http://bcc1.olivernewth.com/houses/the-lindens/

**UPDATE:** I have found a way of doing this now (where the image rotator now vertically centres the image through use of a background). I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it though, as there is no Alt text and isn't compatible with older browsers... Any suggestions?

```
.div {
  background:       url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  width:            960px; 
  height:           384px; 
  background-size:  100%; 
  background-width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: please say, here(link) what you want to change?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will vertical and horizontal align your images.

```
.container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 384px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 382px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.container img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Where the "container" class may be your .div if you choose to insert the image into HTML and not use them as a background